# Proof of Uniform Convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Prove that the sequence of functions $\{f_{n}(z) = (1+nz)^{-1}\mid n=1,2,...\}$ converges uniformly to $f(z)=0$ for $|z| \geq r > 0$. To answer the question, for a given choice of $\epsilon > 0$, you must show how to choose $N$ such that if $n \geq N$, then $|f_{n}(z)-0|=|f_{n}(z)| < \epsilon$.

How would I begin this proof?

Answer (score 4):

HINT: For a fixed $n$, if you know that $|z|\ge r$, what is the largest possible value of $$\left|\frac1{1+nz}\right|\;?$$  Since convergence depends only on what happens in the long run, you may assume that $n$ is big enough so that $nr>1$.

Comment: I'm more confused on how I choose an E and how I can find N to satisfy the condition.